# Online chat: is ASP remote scripting outdated

Tags: asp.net, scripting, chat

I'm looking to implement a cross-browser chat feature for an existing ASP.NET AJAX + Javascript clientside card game.

I've found Remote Scripting samples that look pretty simple, but all articles are dated back 7 to 10 years! (2003 to 2005).

Hence my questions:

1 - is ASP remote scripting outdated

2 - If yes, what solution would you suggest, ASP.NET 4.0 compatible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a lot about remote scripting, but if I were looking to build a real-time chat with ASP.NET today I would take a good look at [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR). More [details here from Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx).